# FirebaseInstanceID file not found Objective c

Tags: ios, firebase, object, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Recently I reintegrated, reinstalled and updated my pods, and Xcode start throwing following error on compile time.

'FirebaseInstanceID/FirebaseInstanceID.h' file not found
[image]

I noticed that FirebaseInstanceID was there but when I tried to newly install pods but it got skipped while installing

[image]

Is there any Alternate of this as I looked into firebase and its looks like it already obsoleted https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId

So I want to know is there any Alternate for this class ? as I have few code base on this class for notification e.g. kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification ?

Please suggest me on this so that I'll resolve issue .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8100:

InstanceID is no longer part of Firebase 8.x. Use FirebaseMessaging APIs instead.

Migration details at https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations#fid-iid